# How to detect tomcat connection pooling issue

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, c3p0

We have a Java Spring MVC 2.5 application using Tomcat 6 and MySQL 5.0 . We have a bizarre scenario where for whatever reason, the amount of connections used in the c3p0 connection pool starts spiraling out of control and eventually brings tomcat down.

We monitor the c3p0 connection pooling through JMX and most of the time, connections are barely used. When this spiraling situation happens, our tomcat connection pool maxes out and apache starts queuing threads.

In the spiraling scenario, the database has low load and is not giving any errors or any obvious bad situation.

Starting to run out of ideas on how to detect this issue. I don't think doing a tomcat stack dump would do me any good when the situation is already spiraling out of control and not sure how I could catch it before it does spiral out of control.

We also use Terracotta which I don't believe by the logs that it is doing anything odd.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: might be you are not closing the session properly after database calls.

Comment: If you are using hibernate you might try to set the connection release mode to after_transaction. We had to override the default on_commit because connections where not given back to the pool and we discovered it with a quick load test with jmeter. Worth a try!

Comment: Ankit: I would assume if this was the case that our application would hang pretty quickly as connections would bleed out quickly. However, this is not the case, the application can run for a month or 2 with traffic and not have a blimp and then do this crazy scenario a few times in a short period of time.

Comment: Martin: I'll have to look into that although I suspect if the connections were not being given back to the pool that I should see my connection pool count go up as this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere you're leaking a connection. This can happen when you explicitly retrieve Hibernate sessions from the session factory, rather than getting the connection associated with an in-process transaction (can't remember the exact method names).

C3P0 will let you debug this situation with two configuration options (following is copied from docs, which are part of the download package):

> unreturnedConnectionTimeout defines a limit (in seconds) to how long a Connection may remain checked out. If set to a nozero value, unreturned, checked-out Connections that exceed this limit will be summarily destroyed, and then replaced in the pool
>
> set debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces to true, then a stack trace will be captured each time a Connection is checked-out. Whenever an unreturned Connection times out, that stack trace will be printed, revealing where a Connection was checked out that was not checked in promptly. debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces is intended to be used only for debugging, as capturing a stack trace can slow down Connection check-out

Comment: Parsifal: I have tried to use those before with no real success but I'll try it again, might be better now that I've got a couple new ideas on where this could be happening. I'll award the answer for this one although I'm really hoping to get answers from others who have experienced the same thing.

Comment: @user2212828 - don't feel obligated to accept the answer if it doesn't meet your needs. If this doesn't work, however, the alternative is to go into the connection pool code and log borrows/returns (I've had to do this for a DBCP pool and don't recommend it except as a last resort).

Comment: Could you tell from the c3p0 code which of your java methods called the connection pool borrows? Ideally, if I knew where in our code this scenario is happening from, that would give me useful information.

Comment: @user2212828 - when you turn on the `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces` option, the pool should create a new `Exception` object, which gives a stack trace showing where the connection was allocated. Assuming that you're using Spring's transaction management, a "normal" connection will be allocated somewhere by Spring, while a "leaked" connection won't. Trying to compare thousands of stack traces is onerous, which is why the pool only logs those connections that time-out.

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully I can reproduce the problem scenario and get those stack traces.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to get a stack trace every time C3P0 checks in a connection? I realize this would make for huge logs. I don't think debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces will work for us as unreturnedConnectionTimeout has to be a value high enough as to not kill active queries but it's high enough that we can't wait this long when the problem occurs, tomcat needs to be restarted right away. So ideally, getting a stack trace of every checkin would be a lot better.